Text.Json fails to serialize schema with derived child classes
I am converting a project from Newtonsoft to Text.Json, I am having a problem with Text.Json failing to serialize records that contain derived records as a child.
E.g.:
public record Parent1
{
    [Obsolete]
    public Child1 Child { internal get; set; } = new();
}

public record Parent2 : Parent1
{
    public Parent2() { }
    public Parent2(Parent1 parent) : base(parent) { }

    [Required]
    public new Child2 Child { get; set; } = new();
}

public record Sub
{
    public string Foo;
    public string Bar;
}

public record Child1
{
    [Obsolete]
    public string CSV { internal get; set; } = "";
}

public record Child2 : Child1
{
    public Child2() { }
    public Child2(Child1 child) : base(child) { }

    [Required]
    public List<Sub> List { get; set; } = [];
}

A test project to demo the behavior, Newtonsoft works fine, Text.Json fails: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CPgUcF
Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Got help on GitHub, need to include IncludeFields = true in settings.
